# Hardware Motherboard Compatibility

Tags: motherboard, compatibility

I have an old computer and I want to upgrade it. I am looking for a motherboard but I think the other components that I have here will not work on the new board.

My specs are these:

[image]

The motherboard I am looking for is this: MSI G41M-S01 (MS-7592).

Anybody here knows if I can buy this board without any compatibility issues?

Comment: You are going to have to proper the specification on the motherboard if you want us to tell you if the CPU you want is compatible or not.  MSI does not have information on your motherboard.  If the motherboard is a LGA775 motherboard it will work, check the CPU compatibility list, to insure compatibility requirements.  The motherboard must require DDR2, if it supports DDR3, then it will not work in your setup.

Comment: How do i know if it is LGA75? On the program that i used it's written only: Motherboard: MSI G41M-S01 (MS-7592)

Comment: E5400 is socket 775.   http://ark.intel.com/products/40478/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5400-2M-Cache-2_70-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: You are the only one able to tell what socket, the motherboard you want to get,  is exactly since MSI has NO information on that model number.  Provide us the specifications, that is something we can look at, and easily answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO**, you need DDR3 RAM, and its a much better idea to get a new computer at this point.
The DDR2 memory that you have is not compatible, as the MSI G41M-S01 has DDR3 RAM slots. DDR3 RAM is cheap though.

I'm assuming you're talking about the motherboard in these links:
http://www.pc-specs.com/mobo/MSI/MSI_G41M-S01_ATX_L775/3011
http://specsen.com/motherboard-msi/msi-g41m-s01/

As for other compatibility,

**CPU**: The E5400 CPU can use the G41 chipset that the MSI-C41M-SO1 has.
http://ark.intel.com/products/40478/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5400-2M-Cache-2_70-GHz-800-MHz-FSB#@compatibility

**RAM**: You need DDR3 RAM, which is cheap, 8 GB, which is apparently the most the motherboard can support, is around 30$.

**Hard Drive**: The MSI G41M-S01 has 4 SATA II slots,
and your Maxtor DiamondMax 21 STM3320820AS has SATA(II), so it works.
http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?item=N82E16822144188

Placa-Mãe means motherboard, according to Google Translate,
semp toshiba informatica ltda STI 005492 is your current motherboard, I guess.
I cannot find out what it is, and I assume that it's not a laptop.

**GPU**: The Geforce GTX 430 uses PCIe, and the MSI G41M-S01 has PCIe, so it works.